# "div p" VS "div * p"? Are they same or different?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I've known about the existence of a so-called "grandchild" selector in CSS until I've seen this [article](https://www.sitepoint.com/premium/screencasts/atoz-css-the-general-sibling-selector). I've played around with it. It seems to me as being just the universal selector (which selects all elements).

Consider the following demo:

```css
.wrap {
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 50px auto;
}

.wrap * p {
  width: 400px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: green;
  margin: 10px;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="item1">
    <p>First</p>
    <div class="item2">
      <p>Second</p>
      <div class="item3">
        <p>Third</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If we remove the `*` from the `.wrap * p` nothing changes.

It's basically the same as `.wrap p` (parent blank child).

So therefore my question:

**Does the grandchild selector `*` make any sense?**

**How `div * p` is different from `div p` notation?**

Comment: Yes `.wrap p` selects the children also which the other one doesn't. You don't see any difference because you don't have a `p` that is a child. Basically, `.wrap p` selects all ***descendant*** `p` of the `.wrap` whereas `.wrap * p` select all ***descendant*** `p` of ***descendants*** of the `.wrap`  but not the `p` directly under the `.wrap`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is a difference.

**Descendants of a parent element can be of 2 types:**

1. Direct Descendants.
2. Indirect Descendants.

For example consider the following markup:

```
<div>
  <em>This is direct descendant</span>
  <p>
    p is also a direct descendant.

    <span>This is indirect descendant</span>
  </p>
</div>
```

In the above code `<em>` and `<p>` are direct while `<span>` is indirect descendants of `<div>`.

**Descendant Selector:**

In css a space works as a descendant selector. For example:

```
div p { ... }
```

The above selector will select all `<p>` elements appearing inside `<div>` (Both direct and Indirect).

In the snippet below all `p` elements will inherit styles.

```css
.wrap p {
  background: green;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <p>Direct p of wrap</p>
  <div class="item1">
    <p>Indirect p of wrap</p>
    <div class="item2">
      <p>Indirect p of wrap</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Direct Descendant Selector:**

`>` is a direct descendant selector. For example:

```
div > p { ... }
```

The above selector will select all `<p>` elements that are direct descendants of `<div>`. This selector will search for the elements only one level down in DOM.

In the snippet below only direct `p` descendants will inherit styles.

```css
.wrap > p {
  background: green;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <p>Direct p of wrap</p>
  <div class="item1">
    <p>Indirect p of wrap</p>
    <div class="item2">
      <p>Indirect p of wrap</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Now, What is `*` selector?**

> `*` is a universal selector which can match any element.

**Indirect Descendants Selectors:**

We can add `*` operator in between any two selectors to select only indirect descendants. For example:

```
div * p { ... }
```

The above selector will select all `<p>` elements inside `<div>` that are indirect descendants (not direct). The `*` selector between `div` and `p` will select will pick `<p>` only when there is some other element (because `*` is a universal selector) between `<div>` and `<p>`.

In the snippet below only indirect `p` descendants will inherit styles.

```css
.wrap * p {
  background: green;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <p>Direct p of wrap</p>
  <div class="item1">
    <p>Indirect p of wrap</p>
    <div class="item2">
      <p>Indirect p of wrap</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Awesome explained. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

`.wrap * p` will select any `p` element inside any children of `.wrap`

```css
.wrap * p {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div>
    <p>TEXT</p>
  </div>
  <p>TEXT 2</p>
</div>
```

While `.wrap p` will also select `p` as children

```css
.wrap p {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div>
    <p>TEXT</p>
  </div>
  <p>TEXT 2</p>
</div>
```